# Coding up a toy model for gradient-descent -- what step size to choose?

Tags: matlab, rootfinding

I'm coding up a simple model for gradient-descent, and using it to minimize some simple, deterministic functions.

What step size could I choose that's simple enough for me to get started with?

Should I choose a constant step size of .1?  .001?  1?  1.5?

On Wikipedia, it gives a model for this step size, called the Barzilai–Borwein method, but this is too complicated for me at the moment.

Besides a constant step size, is there an easy variable-step size I could implement and play with?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to minimize

$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2$$

The gradient is

$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} = A^T(Ax-b)$$

The step size to guarantee convergence is

$$\alpha=||A^TA||^{-1}$$

Why? The direct solution to the problem is:

$$x_{opt}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$
This can be achieved iteratively if we look at the update on the estimate $x_k$. Suppose we start with $x_0=0$, then

$$x_1 = \alpha A^Tb$$
subsequent steps are
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\alpha A^T(Ax_k-b)$$
We can therefore write
$$x_{k+1}=\alpha\left(\sum_{n=0}^k(I-\alpha A^TA)^n\right)A^Tb$$
Using the singular value decomposition $A=USV^T$, we can rewrite the equation as
$$x_{k+1}=\alpha V\left(\sum_{n=0}^k(I-\alpha S^2)^n\right)SU^Tb$$
The sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^k(I-\alpha S^2)^n$$
Is a geometric series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^k x^n$, which we can rewrite as as in the following form as long as $||x||<1$ to guarantee convergence:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
We thus can rewrite:

\begin{align}
x_{opt}&= \alpha V\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(I-\alpha S^2)^n\right)SU^Tb\\
&=\alpha V((\alpha S^2)^{-1})SU^Tb\\
&=VS^{-1}U^Tb
\end{align}
This expression is the same as the one for $x_{opt}$ by noting that

\begin{align}
A^TAx&=A^Tb\\
VSU^TUSV^Tx&=VSU^Tb\\
\Rightarrow x &=VS^{-1}U^Tb 
\end{align}

The only condition we need to ensure is that the singular values in $S$ are rescaled for the sum $\sum_{n=0}^k(I-\alpha S^2)^n$, such that the sum is convergent for $k\rightarrow\infty$. This is why we use the step size

$$\alpha=||A^TA||^{-1}$$
Because it rescales the largest singular value in $S$ to be equal to $1$, which means all other singular values are above $0$ and below $1$. This way, the geometric series will converge.

I hope I didn't do any mistake here, but if anyone finds something, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer to the second part of your question:

"Besides a constant step size, is there an easy variable-step size I could implement and play with?"

An easy way to implement some variable step size would be the following algorithm:
Consider your cost function $\Phi(x)$ you would like to minimize.

- Choose an initial step size $\alpha$
- Choose a starting point $x_0$
- Compute the value of the cost function $c_0=\Phi(x_0)$
- Update $x$ via the step $x_{k+1}=x_k-\alpha\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}$
- Compute the value at the new position $c_{k+1}=\Phi(x_{k+1})$
- Compare the values $c_k$ and $c_{k+1}$:

  - If $c_k<c_{k+1}$ Then

    - Redo the iteration with $x_k$ and decreased $\alpha$, e.g. $\alpha\rightarrow 0.5\alpha$
  - Else

    - Use $x_{k+1}$ for the next iteration and increase the step size $\alpha$, e.g. $\alpha\rightarrow 1.2\alpha$
- Stop after some stopping criterion.